# PHP - Passar várivel do Controller para a view CodeIgniter / Menu ativo

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu quero fazer uma forma do menu ativo ficar colorido, para isso separei o meu template tem:

View:
Menu_lateral.php - lugar onde tem o menu lateral;

Controller: 
Geral: Onde eu iria falar qual o menu está ativo;

Na view eu fiz:

```
<?php
    $ativo = array();
    $ativo[0] = "";

    $ativo[$current] = 'class="active"';
?>
```

E

```
<li class="nav-item <?php echo $ativo[0];?> ">
```

Já no controller:

```
$this->load->view('dashboard/template/menu_lateral', $current = 0);
```

Porem me retorna:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: current

Filename: template/menu_lateral.php

Line Number: 5

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\application\views\dashboard\template\menu_lateral.php
Line: 5
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\application\controllers\Geral.php
Line: 10
Function: view
```

Acredito que eu não esteja carregando certo/chamando corretamente a variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O teu problema está no tipo de dados que estas a tentar enviar para a vista

esta está a espera de uma array com os dados

deves corrigir no teu controlador para algo do genero

```
$this->load->view('dashboard/template/menu_lateral', array('current' => 0));
```

depois na vista para acederes a variabel

```
 $current
```